# Trouble installing & starting Python from command line in Windows 7

Tags: python, windows-7, command-line, windows-7-x64

I'm installing Python for use with [SQLMap](http://sqlmap.sourceforge.net/). I've downloaded and ran the [Python 2.7.2 MSI installer](http://www.python.org/getit/), and restarted my computer. According to everything I've read, I should be able to just call python and SQLMap from the DOS command line using `python sqlmap.py`, but the command line doesnt seem to recognize the `python` - I get a `'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` error.

Do I need to add Python to my path variable? If so, how? Everything I've read says it should work out of the box...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you should add it to your path. Does running `C:\Python27\python.exe sqlmap.py` work?

See for instance https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-to-add-python-to-the-windows-path

Comment: `C:\Python27\python.exe sqlmap.py` works, thanks. I tried adding `;C:\Python27` to the PATH variable as stated in the linked question, but I still get the same error when I try to just use `python` in the CMD line.

Comment: Hmm... did you restart CMD after you edited the path? Because that is necessary for the changes to have effect.

Comment: I have that as my path and restarting CMD doesnt fix it for me, althought using C:\Python27\python.exe sqlmap.py before works but I have to do it every time I want to run a command